# Программа вылетает в рантайме Heap Corruption Detected

Tags: c++

Подскажите, как правильно реализовать класс?

Есть конструктор, принимающий указатель на массив `char`, и присваивающий указатель объекта на этот массив.

Компилируется, но в "рантайме" вылетает... Я так понимаю, из-за того, что передаваемый `const char` создается в стеке:

```
class String {
private:
  char *str;

public:
  String() { this->str = new char[80]; }
  String(char *str) { this->str = str; }
  ~String() { delete[] str; }
};

int main() {
  String str("asdasd");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Учебное задание? Вы удаляете литерал `"asdasd"`, это запрещено вообще-то. Вам надо клонировать строку, которая приходит к вам на вход.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Под строку "asdasd" память не выделяется через new[], следовательно ее нельзя удалять через delete[]. Вот и причина падения. И да, эта строка скорее не создается на стеке, а лежит себе в секции данных и передается только ее смещение, но точнее надо в Иде смотреть.